# Efficiently Turn Matrix of Intersecting Routes Into Simplified Spatial Network (Graph)

Tags: python, r, geospatial, qgis

I have a matrix of real detailed routes which I want to efficiently turn into a simple spatial network. Simple means that I don't care about the intricacies of local transport and possible intersections of routes near the start and end points. I do want to add major intersections outside the start and end points as nodes to the network. Below I give a simple example. My real data has 12,500 routes between 500 start and end points and is approx. 2Gb in size.

```r
library(fastverse)
#> -- Attaching packages --------------------------------------- fastverse 0.3.2 --
#> v data.table 1.15.0     v kit        0.0.13
#> v magrittr   2.0.3      v collapse   2.0.12
fastverse_extend(osrm, sf, sfnetworks, install = TRUE)
#> -- Attaching extension packages ----------------------------- fastverse 0.3.2 --
#> v osrm       4.1.1      v sfnetworks 0.6.3 
#> v sf         1.0.16

largest_20_german_cities <- data.frame(
  city = c("Berlin", "Stuttgart", "Munich", "Hamburg", "Cologne", "Frankfurt",
    "Duesseldorf", "Leipzig", "Dortmund", "Essen", "Bremen", "Dresden",
    "Hannover", "Nuremberg", "Duisburg", "Bochum", "Wuppertal", "Bielefeld", "Bonn", "Muenster"),
  lon = c(13.405, 9.18, 11.575, 10, 6.9528, 8.6822, 6.7833, 12.375, 7.4653, 7.0131,
          8.8072, 13.74, 9.7167, 11.0775, 6.7625, 7.2158, 7.1833, 8.5347, 7.1, 7.6256),
  lat = c(52.52, 48.7775, 48.1375, 53.55, 50.9364, 50.1106, 51.2333, 51.34, 51.5139,
          51.4508, 53.0758, 51.05, 52.3667, 49.4539, 51.4347, 51.4819, 51.2667, 52.0211, 50.7333, 51.9625))

# Unique routes
m <- matrix(1, 20, 20)
diag(m) <- NA
m[upper.tri(m)] <- NA
routes_ind <- which(!is.na(m), arr.ind = TRUE)
rm(m)

# Routes DF
routes <- data.table(from_city = largest_20_german_cities$city[routes_ind[, 1]], 
                     to_city = largest_20_german_cities$city[routes_ind[, 2]], 
                     duration = NA_real_, 
                     distance = NA_real_, 
                     geometry = list())
# Fetch Routes
i = 1L
for (r in mrtl(routes_ind)) {
  route <- osrmRoute(ss(largest_20_german_cities, r[1], c("lon", "lat")),
                     ss(largest_20_german_cities, r[2], c("lon", "lat")), overview = "full")
  set(routes, i, 3:5, fselect(route, duration, distance, geometry))
  i <- i + 1L
}
routes %<>% st_as_sf(crs = st_crs(route))

routes_net = as_sfnetwork(routes, directed = FALSE)
print(routes_net)
#> # A sfnetwork with 20 nodes and 190 edges
#> #
#> # CRS:  EPSG:4326 
#> #
#> # An undirected simple graph with 1 component with spatially explicit edges
#> #
#> # A tibble: 20 × 1
#>              geometry
#>           <POINT [°]>
#> 1  (9.179999 48.7775)
#> 2      (13.405 52.52)
#> 3 (11.57486 48.13675)
#> 4 (10.00001 53.54996)
#> 5   (6.95285 50.9364)
#> 6   (8.68202 50.1109)
#> # ℹ 14 more rows
#> #
#> # A tibble: 190 × 7
#>    from    to from_city to_city duration distance                       geometry
#>   <int> <int> <chr>     <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>               <LINESTRING [°]>
#> 1     1     2 Stuttgart Berlin      390.     633. (9.179999 48.7775, 9.18005 48…
#> 2     2     3 Munich    Berlin      356.     586. (11.57486 48.13675, 11.57486 …
#> 3     2     4 Hamburg   Berlin      176.     288. (10.00001 53.54996, 10.0002 5…
#> # ℹ 187 more rows
plot(routes_net)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Regarding possible solutions I am open to any software (R, Python, QGIS etc.). I know in R there is `tidygraph` which allows me to do something like

```r
library(tidygraph)
routes_net_subdiv = convert(routes_net, to_spatial_subdivision)
```

But this seems to run forever even with this mock example. I have also seen ideas to use [GRASS's v.clean tool](https://r-spatial.org/r/2019/09/26/spatial-networks.html) to break up the geometry, but haven't tried that yet and a bit reluctant to install GRASS.

I think perhaps the best solution for performance is converting to S2 and comparing all linestrings individually using `s2_intersection()` and then turning this information into a graph somehow. But hoping for more elegant and performant solutions.

Comment: How far out would you buffer start/end to hide last x km intricacies while retaining 'major intersections', i.e. is this highway vs local road distinction?, which I think would influence what your 'aggregated structure' is, S2 or otherwise.

Comment: I think I'd ignore intersections within 15km of each city center.

Answer (score 2):

> *I am open to any software (R, Python, QGIS etc.)*

With [python](/questions/tagged/python) and IIUC, you can use this [primal](https://docs.momepy.org/en/stable/generated/momepy.gdf_to_nx.html) approach after getting the available [`directions`](https://openrouteservice-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#module-openrouteservice.directions) :

```py
cities = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    pd.DataFrame(data), crs="EPSG:4326",
    geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(data["lon"], data["lat"])
)

client = openrouteservice.Client(key="") # put here your key

def get_route(coords, as_ls=True):
    res = client.directions(coords, profile="driving-car", format="geojson")
    geom = res["features"][0]["geometry"]
    return shape(geom) if as_ls else geom

combs_lonlat = combinations(cities[["lon", "lat"]].agg(tuple, axis=1), 2)

# maybe we should use a standard loop and add time.sleep(n) ?
lines = [get_route(c) for c in combs_lonlat] # will eventually show warnings

routes = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=lines, crs=4326)
```

***NB**: You'll need to signup to [openrouteservice](https://openrouteservice.org/) in order to generate/get your api key.*

Now, to make the [graph](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/graph.html), you can use [`momepy`](https://github.com/pysal/momepy) :

```py
splines = set()
for ll, rl in combinations(routes["geometry"], 2):
    try:
        for line in split(ll, rl).geoms:
            splines.add(line)
    except ValueError:
        pass

G = gdf_to_nx(
    gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=list(splines)),
    multigraph=False, directed=False,
    approach="primal",
)

len(G.nodes) # 250
len(G.edges) # 1296
```

Plot (*optional*) :

```py
fig, (axl, axr) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

for ax, inp in zip((axl, axr), (cities, G)):
    routes.plot(color="k", ax=ax)
    cities.plot(color="r", marker="x", zorder=3, ax=ax)
    _ = ax.set_title(f"{len(inp)} nodes", fontweight="bold")
    _ = ax.axis("off")

for x, y, name in zip(
    cities["geometry"].x,
    cities["geometry"].y,
    cities["city"]
):
    for ax in (axl, axr):
        _ = ax.annotate(
            name, xy=(x, y), xytext=(3, 3), textcoords="offset points"
        )

(gpd.GeoSeries([Point(n) for n in G.nodes], crs=4326)
     .plot(color="b", marker="o", ax=axr))
```

[image]

Used imports/input :

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import openrouteservice
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import combinations
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point
from shapely.ops import split
from momepy import gdf_to_nx

data = {
    "city": [
        "Berlin", "Stuttgart", "Munich", "Hamburg", "Cologne",
        "Frankfurt", "Duesseldorf", "Leipzig", "Dortmund", "Essen",
        "Bremen", "Dresden", "Hannover", "Nuremberg", "Duisburg",
        "Bochum", "Wuppertal", "Bielefeld", "Bonn", "Muenster"
    ],
    "lon": [
        13.405, 9.18, 11.575, 10, 6.9528, 8.6822, 6.7833, 12.375,
        7.4653, 7.0131, 8.8072, 13.74, 9.7167, 11.0775, 6.7625, 7.2158,
        7.1833, 8.5347, 7.1, 7.6256
    ],
    "lat": [
        52.52, 48.7775, 48.1375, 53.55, 50.9364, 50.1106, 51.2333, 51.34,
        51.5139, 51.4508, 53.0758, 51.05, 52.3667, 49.4539, 51.4347, 51.4819,
        51.2667, 52.0211, 50.7333, 51.9625
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the effort is much appreciated! However, as far as I understand it does not increase the number of nodes and edges beyond the input route data. I need the algorithm to identify intersection points between the routes and add those as nodes to the graph and break up the edges accordingly.

Comment: No worries, I'm not expecting anything ;) One way (*not robust apparently, since there is some missing cross points and there is potentially some duplicates*) is to [`split`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.split) the routes based on their intersections, see update. You may need to test [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137909/intersecting-lines-to-get-crossings-using-python-with-qgis) approach, which will give you more intersections/nodes. And regarding the 15km constraint, I think it'll be easy to include it.

Comment: Literally helps to learn from your solutions @Timeless Sir

Comment: Thank you @MayukhBhattacharya, I learn from your Excel's answers as well ;)